# Whenever I run the website mongoose gives me error and I have not been able to figure it out

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkcVi.png) This the output or error I get after I run my code

This is my code for index.js file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWXCz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4fRv.png)

The code used to run normally before but I don't know if it is an update issue or what ?

Comment: please put the code instead rather than using link(s)

Comment: I tried but stack overflow gives me an error of your question consists mostly code.

Comment: you only need to give more descriptions and put the code inside _``` code goes her```_. well, following the error in your terminal, you connection string is not found or its wrong . check the hostname

Comment: `The code used to run` -> If you are using Atlas MongoDB your db could be idling, please sure your db is not idling by connecting to Atlas MongoDB https://account.mongodb.com/account/login